# Why Spring scheduler stopped unexpectedly

Tags: spring

We have the below scheduler defined in spring context xml file.

```
<!-- Item Scheduling -->
<task:scheduler id="itemScheduler" pool-size="1"/>
<task:scheduled-tasks scheduler="itemScheduler" >
    <task:scheduled ref="itemQueuePoller" method="poll" fixed-delay="10000"/>
</task:scheduled-tasks>
```

and below is the java code for the execution

```
@Service("itemQueuePoller")
public class ItemQueuePoller {

private final Logger LOG = getLogger(ItemQueuePoller.class);

private ItemQueueDao itemQueueDao;
private ItemHandler itemHandler;

@Autowired
public ItemQueuePoller(@Qualifier("itemQueueDao") ItemQueueDao itemQueueDao,
                              @Qualifier("itemHandler") ItemHandler itemHandler) {
    this.itemQueueDao= itemQueueDao;
    this.itemHandler= itemHandler;
}

//scheduled via batch application context
public void poll() {
    try {
        List<ItemQueueEntry> entries = itemQueueDao.findNextBatch();

        if (entries == null || entries.isEmpty()) return;

        itemHandler.processJob(entries);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        LOG.error("Exception occurred while processing Queue Items due to: ", e);
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
}
```

This was working fine everyday but one day it ran only two times and then stopped automatically without any exception in logs.

When we have restarted the application, it starts working fine.

My question is that why it was stopped automatically?

Comment: We have no way of knowing without some sort of logs detailing what lead up to the stopping of the scheduler. It could've been a multitude of things but it's impossible to tell with the information you've provided.

Comment: Hi Jake, There were some DB exception like below for other scheduler but in next run those schedulers ran fine.
2018-03-31 00:02:04.585 [ERROR] [rvrItemScheduler-1] RiskVsRevalItemPoller:40 - Exception occurred while processing Risk vs Reval Queue Items due to:
org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException: Could not get JDBC Connection; nested exception is java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: IO Error: Con
nection reset
        at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.getConnectionework.....

But there was no exception observed in the log for this "itemScheduler".